# innerHTML value in input type Form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, innerhtml

```js
function addRow() {
          
    var SpielerNR = document.getElementById("spielernr");
    var SpielerName = document.getElementById("speilername");
  var groesse = document.getElementById("groesse");
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
 
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
 
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= SpielerNR.value 
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= SpielerName.value 
 row.insertCell(3).innerHTML=  groesse.value
 
}
 
function deleteRow(obj) {
      
    var index = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
    table.deleteRow(index);
    
}
 
function addTable() {
      
    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
      
    var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
    table.border='1';
    
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
      
    for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
       var tr = document.createElement('TR');
       tableBody.appendChild(tr);
       
       for (var j=0; j<4; j++){
           var td = document.createElement('TD');
           td.width='75';
           td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Cell " + i + "," + j));
           tr.appendChild(td);
       }
    }
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
    
}
 
function load() {
    
    console.log("Page load finished");
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML dynamic table using JavaScript</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
<div id="myform">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>NR:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="spielernr"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="speilername"></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>Select:</td>
        <td>
  <select id="groesse" name="groesse" style="width: 150px">
  <option> </option>
  <option value="XXS">XXS  </option>
  <option value="XS">XS </option>
  <option value="S">S  </option>
  <option value="M">M  </option>
  <option value=" L">L </option>
  <option value="XL">XL </option></select>
  </select>
        <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="Javascript:addRow()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="mydata">
<b>Current data in the system ...</b>
<table id="myTableData"  border="1" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><b>NR</b></td>
        <td><b>Name:</b></td>
        <td><b>Grösse</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
&nbsp;
 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My Prob is, when i add NR NAME AND GROESSE.. i will get a plan TEXT. 
what i need is a INPUT form like
 with the added info.

Means:
after i added all infos like Nr NAME and GROESE, i want to show input form instead of plan text.

Any idea, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are already using the `CreateElement()` function in your code a number of times.  Why not use that to create your input element?  All of these things can be done in Javascript.  Maybe use jQuery or some other tool to help simplify some of your DOM manipulation efforts.

Here's another example from a different StackOverflow question:

[How insert an input field in a table cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402067/how-insert-an-input-field-in-a-table-cell)

Comment: Look at the question I to which I created a link.  That is pretty much what you need to do.  The OP's original code, using `document.createElement()` instead of `cell1[0].createElement()`.  If you really need a clearer picture than that I suppose I can copy/paste that into my answer.